# SQL 'IN' operator in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble with creating a LINQ query with `IN` parameters.
Corresponding SQL Query is

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEDEMO WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM TABLE2)
```

How do I achieve the same using LINQ?
I can also take a list variable to store multiple IDs.

```
 (from x in objEntity.TABLEDEMO
 where x.TABLEDEMO (here should be the in parameter)
 select x);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Contains`:

```
from x in objEntity.TABLEDEMO
where objEntity.Table2.Contains(y => y.ID == x.ID)
select x;
```

You can't write this any other, i.e. there is no query style operator you can use.

Answer (score 3):

```
from x in objEntity.Tabledemo
where (from y in objEntity.table2
       select ID).contains(x.ID)
select x
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Any` operator:

```
from x in objEntity.TABLEDEMO
where otherQuery.Any(oq => oq == x.ID)
select x
```